# Como verificar no console as conexões websockets abertas?

Tags: websocket, console, debug

Eu estava analizando como o StackOverflow verifica por atualizações na lista de perguntas, mas nada aparece no console (Firebug), por isso, imagino que estejam utilizando websockets.

Então me surgiu uma dúvida: é possível verificar as conexões websockets abertas através do console (do próprio navegador ou pelo Firebug)? Como?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você estiver usando o Google Chrome pode fazer:

1. Abra a janela de Ferramentas de Desenvolvedor, atalho: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.
2. Clique sobre a aba `Network`.
3. Clique sobre a aba `WebSockets`.
4. Clique no botão *Filter*.

   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/firebug2) é possível fazer isso a partir da versão 2, como citado no [**roadmap**](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_2.0_Roadmap#Sniff_WebSocket_traffic).

Comment: Parece que no Firebug ainda não é possível. No roadmap o websockets ainda está com o status `not started` =s